# Apply Style to controls that derives from a certain base class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

How to apply style to all children that is based on a certain CustomControl.

**Example**

A CustomControl

```
public class SubView : UserControl
{ ... }
```

A control based on the CustomControl

```
public partial class MyView : SubView
{ ... }
```

XAML for MyView

```
<myLibrary:SubView
    xmlns:myLibrary="....">

<Grid>
    <!--Any content-->
</Grid>
</moduleChrome:SubView>
```

The parent *(the children of this grid is set from code run-time)*

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="myLibrary:SubView">
            <Setter Property="MyCustomDependancy" Value="{binding to a shared MyCustomDependancy}"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <myLibrary:SubView/>   <!--This will have the shared MyCustomDependancy-->
    <localFolder:MyView/>    <!--But this will not be affected-->
</Grid>
```

How would one do to let the MyView be affected by the style?

**EDIT**

The origin of this code is dynamic and fairly complex, but I tried to make the question as generic as possible so as many people as possible could be helped by a possible solution, but I guess I made it too generic.
I will probably not be helped by these answers, but I hope someone else will.

Comment: What answer are you looking for then? Why dont't you create a real custom control if that's what you want?

Comment: @mm8 It is a "real" custom control. The SubView is a replacement for usercontrols inside another custom control called View, and those View's are hosted inside a "main" control called "ViewHost". Both the "Views" and the "SubViews" have a dependency class called ViewGate (which allows communication between the Views and the main app) What I wanted to do was to bind the "View"'s ViewGate to its childrens (SubViews) ViewGates since the ViewGate has dynamic properties

Comment: So how is this related to your original question about how the style of the base class is being applied?

Comment: @mm8 The shared dependency property that I though I could set in style. I updated the question

Comment: The original question of "How to apply style to all children that is based on a certain CustomControl" has already been answered, hasn't it? I set the Opacity dependency property in the sample code in my answer and it clearly works. Please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will actually work as expected provided that `SubView` really is a custom control rather than a `UserControl` and has a default template defined in Themes/Generic.xaml.

You can confirm this yourself using the following sample code.

**Themes/Generic.xaml:**

```
<Style TargetType="local:SubView">
    <Setter Property="Opacity"  Value="0.5" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SubView}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Controls:**

```
public class SubView : ContentControl
{
    static SubView()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SubView),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SubView)));
    }
}

public class MyView : SubView
{

}
```

**Usage:**

```
<local:SubView>
    <local:SubView.Content>
        <TextBlock>content 1</TextBlock>
    </local:SubView.Content>
</local:SubView>
<local:MyView>
    <local:SubView.Content>
        <TextBlock>content 2</TextBlock>
    </local:SubView.Content>
</local:MyView>
```

From MSDN: *"If you do need to create a new control, the simplest way is to create a class that derives from UserControl. Before you do so, consider that your control will not support templates and therefore will not support complex customization."*

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Styles only apply to a specific class, they don't get inherited. You can do this, though:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type myLibrary:SubView}">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type localFolder:MyView}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type myLibrary:SubView}} />
```